# Why one user's network profile reputation graph isn't loaded?

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, reputation-graph

[This](https://stackexchange.com/users/446514/gnat?tab=reputation) is the user I am talking about, why the rep graph doesn't work in his profile (maybe the problem is he exhausted his rep graph by [tons of bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered) :D)?

> [image]

He obviously has accounts with over 200 reps, can be seen [there](https://stackexchange.com/users/446514/gnat?tab=accounts).

(And, just by the way, I noticed this bug about 3 or more months ago and thought that it was a temporary problem... but apparently it was not)

Comment: Given the time that page takes to load, I'd say something is timing out. The page takes 10+ seconds to load each time (as measured by the Chrome dev tools).

Comment: @Mart yep, it actually takes *some time* to load...

Comment: The fact that it takes *just over* 10 seconds each time shows it is a query timeout issue; after 10 seconds the server just returns *a* result (without graph, so the default message is there instead), leaving the query to perhaps complete later.

Comment: Takes about 7.5 seconds here, @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Frank exactly 10 for me.

Comment: @Frank: I opened the network tab, set it to filter on the document only, and the graph gives me a time there. Did you use that method or just count?

Comment: I averaged the time it took to reload the page 5 times, used a stopwatch xD @MartijnPieters. It got faster toward the end.

Comment: FWIW my [rep tab at Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=reputation) loads slow as well to me (much slower than at other accounts). Since it feeds network wide graph, it can be related. One difference from my other accounts I can see is there is a lot (10-20 a day average) of -1/+1 events matching answer downvotes and refunds of these when answer I voted down gets deleted

Comment: @gnat yeah, I am still [far from you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=bounties&sort=offered) :D

Comment: but you already caught [minitech](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/160410/minitech?tab=bounties) :)

Comment: this seems to be fixed recently. Last few weeks I tried getting to network profile several times, every reputation graph loads and is displayed fine. There is typically a noticeable delay, like 10-20-30 seconds but eventually it gets there

Comment: @gnat Yep, looks like you're right! You may want to update your answer :)

Comment: looks like this page broke again - this time in a bit different way - it shows me "offline for maintenance" message. At first I thought maybe it's indeed offline for maintenance but trying rep graphs of some other users has shown them without any errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: as of May-June 2016, this appears to be fixed. Clicking [reputation tab at network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/446514/gnat?tab=reputation) appears to load the graph ([screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIWAl.png)). For the sake of completeness, I typically observe a noticeable delay in loading, last time it was about a minute.

---

This issue seems to be related to my voting habits. I have many (I think few thousands) `-1` reputation change events related to downvoting answers. I also have similar amount of rep change events related to rep refunds when such answers are deleted. I am not trying to make it a *zero sum game* but it seems that more than half of the answers I vote down are eventually deleted, resulting in `+1` rep changes (I wouldn't be surprised if it's 80 or maybe even 90%).

Most of these rep change events are at Programmers and it's hardly a coincidence that I experience noticeable delay when loading my profile over there (FWIW these delays don't seem to happen when I load it when logged out). [Prior to recent profile changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251279/why-one-users-network-profile-reputation-graph-isnt-loaded#comment820442_251279), I experienced such delays only when loading my reputation tab over there but now whole profile loading slows down, as if the system tries to prefetch my rep changes even though rep tab is not displayed.

At Workplace, my downvoting activity is lower but for various reasons `-1` rep changes are less... "amortized" over there, allowing to easily see the trend at [my profile activity tab](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/168/gnat?tab=topactivity):

<kbd>[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swo4d.png]</kbd>

---

Worth noting that these issues appear to be related to the *kind* of rep change events, but not to their *amount*.

In more typical cases, system doesn't seem to have difficulties accounting for thousands / tens thousands of reputation change events. As an example, [top rep users at Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) certainly have several thousands rep changes (100K rep means there were about 10K upvotes and accepts) but their reputation graphs load fine and without delays.

[Top rep users at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) make even more prominent example - they've got 5-10x more rep change events than those at Programmers but still, system loads their reputation graphs pretty fast.

It is as if system generally "knows" how to account for multiple rep change events but this "knowledge" is not being used to optimise events related to downvoting other's answers or rep refunds when such answers are deleted.

Comment: ...not that I complain mind you, it simply looks like an interesting programming problem

Comment: I'm very impressed with your posts and bounties in offering. Great contribution to SE. I have featured you in my [**bounty count**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258230/show-count-of-bounties-earned-or-offered-on-profile-page) post.

Comment: Oh, right. I meant to come back and update this but got sidetracked. The SQL upgrade to 2016 brought with it various optimizations (some from the software, some from additional work we ended up doing :)) that fixed up this issue.

Comment: thanks for explaining this @Adam! would be interesting to learn if upgrade also fixed an issue with loading 'all actions' tab of some users' profiles [reported here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278629/165773), since per my recent checks (not very thorough though) it also seems to be gone

Comment: @AdamLear [meta-tag:status-its-back] :) For last day or two I am getting "Oops! Something Bad Happened" when trying to get to my [network rep graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/446514/gnat?tab=reputation) and additionally to [Stack Overflow activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=topactivity). Folks at Tavern [seem to see issues too](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7062098#7062098), rene said it looks like sql query times out

Comment: @gnat Fun! I'm out of the office for the rest of the week. I'll try to remember to check on this next week, but if you don't hear from me... ping again, please.

Comment: @AdamLear pinging as you asked. :) My network rep graph and tab still seem to be in trouble but SO activity tab now loads fine (the latter is possibly related to [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311765/user-profile-page-takes-15-20-seconds-to-load-on-first-load-in-x-minutes?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1020063_311765))

Comment: @gnat Yeah, I think all of that is related. Judging by that other report, folks are aware and looking into it, so hopefully a fix is coming soon.

Comment: @gnat Try your SO activity tab now, it should be a bit faster.

Comment: @Taryn you are right, it is faster indeed, thanks!

Comment: @gnat I'm still looking at the other page issues as well

Comment: @Taryn thanks for taking care of it! my network rep graph seems to be a tough nut to crack :)

Comment: @gnat Alrighty try your network rep graph and see if it loads?

Comment: @Taryn wow, magic! it loads well and fast now. You know, yesterday I tried to figure how it could be solved and the more I thought about this the more it felt like really difficult design challenge. Mind sharing how you did that? There is some caching because it "delays" my recent rep bump at MSE but I think it can't be plain caching because it seems too expensive to do for all users in the network for such an infrequently used query. I am really intrigued

Comment: @gnat The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312870/164200) explains what we have done. Basically, a bad plan - sql was trying to do something similar `cross join` on rep history and was reading millions of rows when it needed far fewer. We are trying a query hint of `LEFT HASH JOIN` and it's flying now and giving us the plan we expected in the first place.

Comment: thank you @Taryn - TIL