# Is REPUTATION box only for displaying positively gained reps. since your last visit?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page

Earlier today, I started a bounty (with 50 reps.) on my question "[Show count of bounties earned or offered on Profile Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258230/show-count-of-bounties-earned-or-offered-on-profile-page)" and as per the rule it deducted 50 reps. from my total reputation immediately upon applying. Here is the screenshot of the same:

> [image]

I was expecting to see "-50" reputation (in a Red box) gained since my last visit next to my total reps. in the REPUTATION box. But all I see is my new total reps. 2,090 (2,140 - 50). It does show a "-50" reps. that I have earned (in a Blue background box) next to my "reputation" tab.

When you get an up-vote on your post, you will see either +5 (for a question) or +10 (for an answer) reputation gained since your last visit in a little Green background box next to the total reps. (at '?' mark spot in the above screenshot) shown in the REPUTATION box.

So, is REPUTATION box only for displaying positively gained reps. since your last visit? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: See also the feature request to correct this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208900/179419

Comment: Can someone please explain how's this question is "exact duplicate of..."? It may be related but "not exact". That question is talking about achievements in topbar" whereas mine is about "REPUTATION box"

Comment: You asked for an explanation and have one from a developer. Negative reputation changes are not notified on.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I don't get it but I will just leave it. If "reputation since my last visit" is only seen by me (not public) and I have been shown right on face i.e. "-50" reps. that I have earned (in a Blue background box) next to my "reputation" tab. Also shown to me in the top "achievements" notification in bright red color text for "-50"... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tooltip of the box explains it all (emphasis mine):

> Reputation **gained** since your last visit to the reputation tab

Although mathematically you could claim that you gained -50 points, in common language that's a loss of 50 reputation. For one reason or another both the top bar and the reputation gained box only show reputation that is gained, probably because positive feedback has a far stronger effect than negative feedback (not to say that negative feedback isn't important, but negative feedback should from a UX perspective be accompanied with actionable information as much as possible, which a single `-2` can not do).

Comment: But look at what the tooltip of the 'reputation tab' says "reputations you have earned" so it is ok to say that with -50 (ie. negative number)

Comment: @HackerKarma Well, I guess it wouldn't be bad if they wouldn't show negative reputation there either from a UX point of view yeah.

Comment: That's the thing I don't understand. Why show there and not up. But, you did good job on answering "gained" part +1 for that.

Comment: @HackerKarma Ehm, I am pretty sure you don't get reputation notifications for downvotes and the like...? (they are unactionable and strongly demotivational).

Comment: Deleted earlier comments and here is the merged one -  Also, isn't that visible to me only and not public? So, why worry about negative? I know already why I got negative reps. I even got notifications about it in red color -50 reps. for the bounty I started. I just visited to your activity tab and I don't see +10 in green box neither +10 next to 'reputation' tab below.

Comment: @HackerKarma With something like a bounty it's obvious, but far more common are downvotes (both your own and the ones by other users). They are the negative feedback I am talking about.

Comment: I agree that part but even then what do say about the rest of the comment questions I asked in it.

Comment: @HackerKarma Not sure I am able to parse your comment. Are you referring to your question about it being public or not? Because 'reputation since user's last visit' obviously only makes sense for you yourself and is indeed not shown to other users.

Comment: Exactly... So if "reputation since my last visit" is only seen by me then why bother if it is +positive or -negative reps. Why not just show it? Why make negative reps. finding harder i.e. click reputation tab and count the total -negative reps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/916/discussion-between-david-mulder-and-hackerkarma).