# Link to the new mod dashboard sometimes shows up for regular users

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, moderator-tools

The spiffy new mod dashboard is great, but the link sometimes shows when it shouldn't. For example, see [Jeff Atwood's profile on Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/56/jeff-atwood):

[image]

After a bit of experimentation, it seems that the link only shows for non-moderators when:

- The site in question has not received the new CSS updates (hence the example of Security.SE).
- The user whose profile is being viewed has a diamond (hence Jeff Atwood).

When both of these conditions are satisfied, the "mod dashboard" link shows up even for regular, non-moderator users.

Comment: For anyone who's curious and goes to check, the link ends in a 404 error.

Comment: Dash an important one.

Comment: @Emrakul Your bad puns make me board.

Comment: @Doorknob I wish you'd be a little more moderate with your word choice!

Comment: @Emrakul Making so many puns won't help you keep a low profile.

Comment: Our sekrits are being revealed!  Next thing you know, it could allow access to TL for regular users.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, in our defense, you *can't* spell `currentUser.IsModerator` without `u`, which also happened to be the variable denoting the user whose profile you're viewing...

Comment: Psshhh, that's a terrible variable name anyway. :P

Comment: @Doorknob *U* are a terrible variable name. ;)

Comment: wonder what defense would you have for [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251279/165773). "You know gnat, some users are weird... just too weird..." :)

Comment: @gnat Huh. That *is* an interesting one. But you obviously know how it is. All users are special to us... but some just a little bit more than others. ;)