# Extremely long load times for flag history page

Tags: bug, flag-history, performance

Somewhat recently (as in the few days), the flag history summary became extremely slow on Stack Overflow ([direct link to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1849664) for devs), and proportionately longer on other sites:

[image]

On SR, I saw a 700ms load time - roughly proportional to the number of flags I have there. I also saw higher than average load times on Drupal.

There's speculation that it's a nightly job running, slowing things down... but I'd still call that a bug, or at least worth looking in to.

Comment: My [so] flag history takes ~29s to load. My [unix.se] flag history loads human-instantly with almost exactly the same number of flags.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, your flag history loads nearly instantly for me.

Comment: @Shog9 Loading fine for me now, too. Is there a job that finished or something?

Comment: My flag history (a total of 2 whole flags!) loads instantly

Comment: possibly related: [Why one user's network profile reputation graph isn't loaded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251279/why-one-users-network-profile-reputation-graph-isnt-loaded) System seems to optimise only typical events. Flags and votes down are probably not optimised