# 'all actions' tab of some users' profiles takes forever to load

Tags: bug, profile-page, recent-activity, performance

When attempting to view the 'all actions' tab on some users' profiles, the page takes forever to load. For instance, attempting to load [Fred -ii-'s 'all actions' tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii?tab=activity) takes just about 2 seconds. For some other users, like [gnat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=activity), it's not quite so horrible (for gnat it's a little over 1 second) -- it likely depends upon the number of actions a user has performed. Could this be fixed so each page load doesn't require getting up and grabbing a cookie?

Comment: We can still blame caching... only is caching broken in this case...

Comment: Either caching or a query plan gone wildly wrong, @rene.

Comment: try [gnat's all actions at Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=activity) :) (@rene this could be query plan for +1/-1 rep changes of answer downvotes and refunds of these, see eg [Why one user's network profile reputation graph isn't loaded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262016/165773))

Comment: Would you stop breaking things, @gnat? ;)

Comment: maybe when they figure a way to tame proliferation of [low answers quality in hot questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5413/31260). :) Technically it would be really [not complicated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247195/165773) but they seem to be too envy of Reddit to cut that mess